# Hibernate not saving some properties

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a project using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate and one of my entities has a pretty weird behaviour: it's not saving some of the properties. The code below is my model class. It has some more properties and but all of them are String with the `columnDefinition="TEXT"`. Debugging the object I'm sending to the repository all properties have values in it, `get` and `set` methods are working fine, etc.. but it only saves the `title`.

Now comes the weird part, if I do this `Column(name = "isbn_v", columnDefinition="TEXT")` it saves the data normally. The same for all columns that are not saving. I don't understand why. Model class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "notice")
public class Notice implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4521230269805147556L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "seq_no", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "title", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "isbn", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String isbn;
    
    @Column(name = "issn", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String issn;
    
    @Column(name = "author", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "publisher", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String publisher;
    
    // get / set 
}
```

Repository class:

```
public interface NoticeRepository extends JpaRepository<Notice, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Notice> {

    @Override
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    Notice save(Notice notice);
}
```

Any clue of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the db schema correspond to this model?

Comment: @SergeyVasnev yes, it does.

Comment: Did you check the logged generated SQL queries?